# Upper Riemann Sum - Am i Finished?

Tags: calculus

Im trying to find an upper Riemann Sum for $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^{2}}$ on the interval [0,1] and got to the form $ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{n}{n^{2}+i^{2}}$ is this finished or do i have to use the summation of series of $i^{2}$ and then simplify and take the limit as $n\to\infty$. Which would be $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{6n}{2n^{3}+9n^{2}+n} = \frac{1}{2}$
I don't feel this is right.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: By "upper" Riemann sum, are you referring to a right-sided Riemann sum? Are you given a number of rectangles?

Comment: yeah the right-sided, and n number of rectangles

Comment: Are you sure "upper" means right endpoint? It often refers to using the maximum value of the function on each subinterval.

Comment: The formula that works when $i^2$ is in the numerator of the summation does not work when $i^2$ is in the denominator, so your "simplification" gives a wrong result.

Comment: in my notes i have the upper riemann sum as $U(f,P) = \sum _{i=1}^{n} M_{i}= (t_{i}-t_{i-1})$

Comment: @DavidK do i have to get $i^{2}$ up to the numerator?

Comment: Shouldn't the summand be $\frac{1}{1+(i/n-1/n)^2}1/n=\frac{n}{n^2+(i-1)}$? It asks for "a" Riemann sum which I understand that we don't have to specify $n$ any further other than $>1$.

Comment: The upper Riemann sum is left rectangular rule since $f(x)$ is decreasing.  Did you mess up $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{n}{n^{2}+k^{2}}$ with $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{n^{2}+k^{2}}{n}$? You know $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{1+x^{2}}=\frac{\pi}{4}$, so the Riemann sum won't be a simple rational function in $n$.  The $k^{2}$ term appears in denominator, you can't simplify it.